# Regex for letters numbers space and backslash in kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I want to use regex in kotlin to allow only this kind of strings each strings is length of 15 and can be of any long I just kept 3 numbers as example.

```
"123456789101236 \n 123456789101237 \n 123456789101238"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Adam Millerchip for updating. I'll be thankful if you'll help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```regex
\d{15}(?: \n \d{15})*
```

This assumes that you want only numbers of length 15.  If you want any character, then use `.{15}` in place of `\d{15}`.

Kotlin code:

```kotlin
val input = "123456789101236 \n 123456789101237 \n 123456789101238";
val regex = "\\d{15}(?: \n \\d{15})*".toRegex()
if (regex.matches(input)) {
    println("MATCH")  // prints MATCH
}
```